# How is the voltage resulting from the full wave rectifier equal to 10.2?

Tags: diodes

[image: the probe after the bridge how is that possible ?]

How is that possible? Shouldn't it be much less?

Comment: Just so you know, 120VAC from the wall is not 120Vpk. It's 120Vrms. But Vpk are almost used interchangeably Vpk-pk in some places. Not sure why your voltage seems to double just before the rectifier and then doubles again right after. Pretty weird. Sometimes simulation software has corrupt memory for the file so I would try rebuilding that circuit in a new file from scratch. Not copy pasting or anything.

Comment: repeated it and still gives me the same answers I wonder how before rectification it's 2.5 and after is 10.2

Comment: Falstead gives me what I expect. Your simulator does not, assuming V2 = 120Vpk actually means peak. Because Probe 2 says it is interpreting 120Vpk as peak-to-peak. That's the first point where things start not matching up.

Comment: Well I don't trust probes 2 or 3 because I have no idea what it is measuring with respect to. For example, the primary side of your transformer is not connected to ground at all but your probe is single-ended so how is it measuring the voltage there? Of course, that doesn't explain why probe 1's reading is also messed up.

Comment: @ahmedelsayed Do you mean voltage? Your title says current.

Comment: OMG! my fault have been studying for 2 days truly sorry @Andyaka

Comment: @ahmedelsayed Try altering the initial phase angle of the applied voltage to be 90 degrees and tell me what the dc voltages are like now please. At the moment it is shown as 0 degrees and, if your simulation only calculates the first peak in the first cycle, inrush current will be the answer.

Comment: reading after transformer 2.51

Comment: after the bridge is 10.2 which I don't understand

Comment: To get a sensible reading on the first probe you need to ground one side of the transformer (for simulation purposes only, of course). It's reading half because of hidden resistors or something. Do a transient voltage simulation or I don't think you'll get good results. For example, the ripple at PR4 should be more like 6mV than 20nV, more than 5 orders of magnitude off.